# Display Problems With Arrows on Nivo Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I decided to take my next jump web development, and I thought I'd work with the Nivoslider.

I can't get the arrows to display!  They do work though, even though they are invisible - in going to next and previous slide.

Here is my NIVO CSS Code:

```
    /* Nivo Slider Starts CSS starts Here */

.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:95%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;

    max-width: none;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;

}

/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:6;
    display:none;
    background:white; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
    opacity:0;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }

/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:40px;
    background:#000;
        height:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=8);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:1000;
    cursor:pointer;
        display:block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        text-indent:9999px;
        background: url(arrows_1.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        opacity: 1; /* NEW */ 
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 

}
a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;        
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
    right:15px;

}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
    position: absolute;
     top:600px;
    padding: 15px 0;
        width:100px;
        float:right;


}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}


/* Nivo Slider Ends CSS starts Here */
/
```

I've tried a bunch of different things but nothing has worked yet and now my brain is fried.

I would appreciate any help!  Thanks a lot guys.
-PJ

Comment: Your image path is wrong. background: url("arrows_1.png");

Comment: Well... that may have been the case. But wouldn't you see the default image file missing where the arrows should be if that were the case?

Comment: the image isn't in an image folder, it's in the same dir as the index.php. I added the quotes like you had above - still not working..

Comment: The right path is this: url("../arrows_1.png"); You should learn how to move between the folders.

Comment: @Peege151 No, you wouldn't see the "image file missing" image because it's being loaded in the CSS. That only shows up if you're using `<img src="broken-link" />` No `img` tag, no 'image file missing' image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser is telling me there is no file called "arrows_1.png". You probably have an incorrect file path to the image.

```
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:1000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-indent:9999px;
        background: url(arrows_1.png);//here is the error.
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    opacity: 1; /* NEW */ 
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;  
}
```

Comment: This is the URL your CSS is using. http://emmymudgemusic.com/CSS/arrows_1.png You need to change the URL to read `background: url('/arrows_1.png');

Comment: That is correct. In CSS it's relative to where the CSS is, not the PHP file. If your CSS is in `<style>` tags in your page, it's from that page, but not if you're linking to a css file.